# Main breaker not turning off oven

Tags: electrical-panel

Something very strange is going on at my mother’s house. The oven, which is not built in but just a pigtail plug has been malfunctioning. She has ordered a new oven and is ready to put it in.

When trying to cut power to the outlet, there are no breakers that work. She’s even had my brother go under the house to see if there’s another box somewhere and there is not.

They have cut off the main breaker to the house and everything is off but the oven remains on.

Comment: What do you mean by "*main breaker*", a main shut off in the breaker box or the main disconnect on the service panel/meter on the outside of the house? Power has to enter the house somewhere, can you see where that is?

Comment: How are you testing to know that it has power? "*just a pigtail plug has been malfunctioning*" More details/info on what that means please.

Comment: Picture and location please! For many years the NEC allowed up to 6 properly grouped breakers to function as a residential service.One breaker labelled main often only turns off a portion of the panel, leaving range, dryer, hwt and other circuits to make up the other 5 allowed disconnects.

Comment: Clearly I know nothing about electric, so hopefully this makes sense...even when she shuts off the whole house power from the breaker located outside the house the oven stays on. The lights are on and it heats up and functions.

Comment: I’m assuming she will just need to call an electrician but I just didn’t know if we were missing anything obvious. Every single breaker flipped to the off position does not affect the oven’s power. They went outside and turned off all power to the home and everything is off, but the oven continues to function???

Comment: If it's an electric oven, it'll probably be connected to a 40 amp breaker that takes up two slots.  If power was indeed shut off from outside the house and it remains on, then you must have a magic oven or it has a separate line coming into the house. (neither would make any sense)

Comment: You could consider editing this question into "Help me figure out which breaker shuts off the oven." Include photos showing the area where the electric service attaches to the house (whether overhead or underground and electrical panels around the meter. If you're comfortable doing so, remove the "dead front" (face plate) from the circuit breaker panel there by the meter and attach a photo of the interior of that panel.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease  Yeah, those were called a "split buss panel".  Questions for the OP:  Is there anything else that "stays on" like an electric water heater, electric clothes dryer, furnace?   How old is the house? can you send pics of the main panel?

Comment: Can you post a picture of the electric meter and all the equipment right next to the meter?  Weather doors open, do not remove any screws and definitely don't break any power company seals!  Also, turn everything off and watch the meter.  It should be still.  Then turn the oven on - does the meter disc spin, or any little LCD segments change or dance or do a marqee effect?   I'm wondering if they wired it to the wrong side of the meter in order to steal power.

Comment: I agree with no sparks & George there can be up to 6 breakers legally in a split buss but I have seen more when some are single pole a code violation but someone filled the slots thinking they were ok to use.

Comment: Can you post photos of your electrical panel please, as well of your electric meter and the equipment at the meter?

Comment: "They went outside and turned off all power" - your meter has a disconnect? Well, that's how you wire up to steal power and pull the meter w/o killing yourself.

Comment: Well done, Whitney, you've got the whole squad on this mystery. The only person missing is Inspector Clousseau. "It's a bemm."